# Strange left padding in xamarin forms list view in IOS

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am having troubles getting ListView aligned properly in iOS, Androind is fine

There are 2 issues:

First one, on iOS I am getting a left padding/margin on list view inside a stack panel which I don't know where it is coming from (see image here: https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/thumbnails/FileUpload/b7/8fa8930c5f40605e51e4697d2e4285.png)

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" lb:GridLayout.RowHeights="Auto,*,Auto">
        <shared:Header TextColor="#357dd3" TitleText="NEW ACCOUNT" />

        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid lb:GridLayout.RowHeights="Auto,Auto,*" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" lb:GridLayout.ColumnWidths="*,*,*" HeightRequest="80" VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="login_details_add.png" Aspect="AspectFit" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" lb:GridLayout.ColumnWidths="*,7*,*" VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <shared:PageTitle Grid.Column="1" Padding="20" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            TitleText="Address Details" 
                                            DescriptionText="To give you the best possible search suggestions we need to know your address." />
                </Grid>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Padding="20">
                    <Grid RowSpacing="2" lb:GridLayout.RowHeights="Auto,10,*">
                        <entries:FloatingLabelTextBox Grid.Row="0" Placeholder="Your street address (unit optional)" Text="{Binding SearchText}" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="SearchText" Keyboard="Text" />

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" IsVisible="{Binding HasResults}">
                            <ListView x:Name="SearchResults" ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAddress}">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                  <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextCell Text="{Binding StreetAddress}" Detail="{Binding StateSuburbPostcode}" />
                                  </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <ListView.Footer>
                                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ListView.Footer>
                            </ListView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>

                    <StackLayout Margin="20">
                        <buttons:ActionButton Grid.Column="1" Text="Enter Manually" Command="{Binding ManualEntry}" />
                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
```

I tried different things to no avail.

Second, I am getting 10 search results, but list view keeps putting empty rows below which I fixed by putting empty footer in. This fixed empty rows being rendered, but there is still big empty space below listview. How do I remove it? For now I have a code in my view code behind file, that calculates number of search results, multiplies it by row height and sets list view height, but this feels dirty.

Comment: I dont know what your view should look like but you have done a very complexed Xaml Hierarchy in my opinion. regarding you issues:
first issue - try remove padding="20".
second issue-  change Second row height definition from * to auto.